# Ora2pg Installation dmake command warning

Tags: oracle, postgresql, ora2pg

I am tring to install `ora2pg` on windows for database migration from `oracle to postgresql` and have installed `strawberry perl` but the command `dmake && dmake install` is not working.
When I have tried `gmake && gmake install`, I got the following error, can you please help me with the installation.

```
C:\ora2pg-19.1>gmake && gmake install
to undefined at C:/Perl64/lib/ExtUtils/Install.pm line 141.
gmake: *** [Makefile:938: pm_to_blib] Error 255
```

Answer (score 0):

You are on Windows and you can't chain the cmds as written.  Do gmake, then gmake install.

Comment: Please, can you extend your answer with more detailed explanation? This will be very useful for understanding. Thank you!